# Unresolved crate-to-crate reference in workspace

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a workspace with two crates, and I'd like one to use the other.  Roughly:

```
├── Cargo.toml:
│     [workspace]
│     members = [ "alpha", "beta", ]
├── alpha/
│   ├── Cargo.toml:
│   │     [package]
│   │     name = "alpha"
│   │     edition = "2021"
│   │     ...
│   └── ...
└── beta/
    ├── Cargo.toml:
    │     [package]
    │     name = "beta"
    │     edition = "2021"
    │     [dependencies]
    │     alpha = { path = "../alpha" }
    │     ...
    └── ...
```

However, when I write `use alpha::something` in code in `beta`, I get the error `use of undeclared crate or module alpha`.  Oddly, VSCode seems to understand what's going on, sees the code inside alpha, and offers autocompletes based on it.  However, the rust analyzer is not happy about it.

I've checked the edition match, doublechecked paths, cleaned the build multiple times, verified there's no other `alpha` module in `beta`.  I'm completely confused.

Any tips on how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

This means that the package `alpha` does not provide a library crate that can be depended on by the compiler compiling `beta`. The usual causes of this are:

- Not having an `alpha/src/lib.rs` file.
- `alpha/Cargo.toml` declaring a `crate-type` for the library that does not include `"lib"` (or `"rlib"` or `"dylib"`).

If neither of these is the solution, please update your question to include the full contents of `alpha/Cargo.toml`.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing lib.rs.  Fixing that uncovered a mess of other problems that I also didn't understand, but I compile now.  Not sure why the directory structures of the package system seem to be the most challenging part of learning Rust, even after reading the book chapter about 6 times....  Thank you!